# Only shows navigation for slides in section with Beamer and Metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am using [Beamer](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) with [Metropolis](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/metropolis/doc/metropolistheme.pdf) theme. I am trying to get the table of content that would include the subsections too, as found in [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101206/beamer-mini-toc). So my rough document is something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

% Table of content
\begin{frame}[plain]{Table of contents}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball unnumbered]
    \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[ball unnumbered]
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First}
\subsection{A}
\begin{frame}
    Something something
\end{frame}

\subsection{B}
\begin{frame}
    Something something more
\end{frame}

[...]

\end{document}
```

This gives me the table of content as I wanted. However, this makes the title navigation stacking up and including all the subsections too.[image] Is there anyway that I can only show one row of circle navigation that only includes the frames in the section only (and ignoring the subsection division)?